# Mongo db - Property 'mongoOperations' threw exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I try to use spring-data-mongodb 1.2.0.RELEASE and spring 3.1.3.RELEASE like your case but I get an error:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'mongoOperations' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext;)V
```

This happens when I extend my repository from Repository like this:

```
public interface JsonDataRepository extends Repository<JsonData, String> {  
    List<JsonData> findBySourceTableAndSourceId(String sourceTable, Long sourceId);
}
```

I have a xml configuration equals to your post. Please tell me if is missing an annotation in my repository?????

Answer (score 0):

Can you extent `MongoRepository` instead of `Repository`

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface JsonDataRepository extends MongoRepository<JsonData, String> {  
    List<JsonData> findBySourceTableAndSourceId(String sourceTable, Long sourceId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks by the answer.  I did the extend of MongoRepository but despite off that my junit test is showing the same error. Then I made a deploy of the artifact and it works.
I think my junit test was not loading the whole context.